# Create Clickable Links for Dropdown Menu Options in PHP

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu, textbox

I'm making a system where a user can search through a library by specific fields.

I currently have a PHP document called *index.php* that contains a drop down box, a text box, and a submit button. The user selects from the drop down box which field they want to search through (for example Author or Title), then enters their search criteria in the text box (for example "Tolkien" or "The Hobbit") and then clicks on the submit button which then loads *simpleSearch.php*. The text the user searches for and the field they are searching through are defined on *simpleSearch.php* as follows:

```
$queryString = $_GET["userSearch"]; // get user's search string
$queryType = $_GET["searchType"]; // get user's search type
```

What I would like to have is a different layout but the same functionality on the *index.php* page. [image: Layout Example] The layout above the double blue line is the current layout. The layout below the double blue line is my desired layout.

Instead of choosing a field from the drop down box and clicking on Submit the user would enter their search criteria and then click on one of the fields. The button would act as the drop down selector AND the submit button at the same time.

Here is my code for the current layout:

```
<form action="simpleSearch.php" method="get">
    <select name="searchType">
        <option value="all">All Fields</option>
        <option value="author">Author</option>
        <option value="title">Title</option>
        <option value="subject">Subject</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="userSearch">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Any help at all would be really appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about use:

```html
<form action='simpleSearch.php' method='get'>
  <input type="text">
  <input type="submit" value="all" name="userSearch">
  <input type="submit" value="author" name="userSearch">
  <input type="submit" value="title" name="userSearch">
  <input type="submit" value="subject" name="userSearch">
</form>
```

And in *simpleSearch.php* u can get value by `$_GET['userSearch']`

and dont forget to SQL inject danger ;)

Comment: That's exactly what I needed! Very much appreciated, thanks! And I totally forgot about SQL Injection. I'll have to look into that at some point.